# What should be the schema for the data mentioned below in pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

({(b,c),(d,e)})

I tried it with:  (t1:tuple(B1:Bag{(a:chararray,b:a:chararray)}));
But no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is : (t1:tuple(B1:Bag{t2:tuple(t2a:chararray,t2b:chararray)}))